# Get multiple checkbox values with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this form which i submit using ajax and jquery ,
well, i have this multiple checkbox from which i get some values.

Now i am doing an error here since the values of the checkbox are not being posted in the database..
Here is the html/php part :

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$row['regione'].'" id="regioni_gestite_ag" name="regioni_gestite_ag[]">' . $row['regione'] . '<br>';
    }
```

This is how i get it with javascript:

```
var js_regioni_gestite_ag = $('input:checkbox[name=regioni_gestite_ag]:checked').val();
```

If i echo the value, i get undefined... 
Why is it so?

Comment: try using `$('input:checkbox[name=regioni_gestite_ag[]]:checked')` instead.

Comment: I have tried it and well, nope, it won't take it..

Comment: ids are singular! You have more than one checkbox with the same id.

Comment: It works if i use plain php , which means it must be the problem with js!

Comment: @Kledi See my response. It checks if any boxes are checked and if so, gets their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var js_regioni_gestite_ag = [];//[name="regioni_gestite_ag[]"]
if($('input[name="regioni_gestite_ag[]"][type=checkbox]:checked').length){
    // check if any checkboxes are checked
    $('input[name="regioni_gestite_ag[]"][type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(o){
        // get their values
        js_regioni_gestite_ag.push($(this).val());
    });
}

// clears all selected checkboxes
function clearSelection() {
    $('input[name="regioni_gestite_ag[]"][type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(o){
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work because apparently, i am outputting the wrong way the form, it takes the values from the id, not the name..

Comment: I'll have to accept this :)
it worked, i had an error inside the form, apparently :)
thanks a lot!

Comment: but one question please, how can i clear the form after submission?
this is how i do it now:
$("#regioni_gestite_ag").prop("checked", false);

Comment: You should avoid using :checkbox selector extension, since it is deprecated (for eventual removal). Instead, use [type="checkbox"] http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9400

Comment: @Kledi - Use the `clearSelection` function to clear all checkboxes.

Comment: Pushpesh, one last question please, i feel like a dumb girl now :/
if i insert it just like that, it won't clear the values...
i just copy pasted :/

Comment: You have to call the function when you want to clear the values. Do `clearSelection()` after you have read the values.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are not specifying the `name` attribute correctly. The selector should be

```
$('input[name="regioni_gestite_ag[]"]:checkbox:checked')
```

However, that will still not make everything work because [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) only returns the value of the *first* matched element (so it will only apply to the first checkbox).

Finally, your PHP code produces multiple elements with the same `id` attribute, which is illegal HTML and will make random jQuery and/or DOM APIs not work correctly. This should be fixed immediately, perhaps by removing the `id` entirely?

**Update**: to get the values of all checkboxes as an array you can use

```
var values = $.makeArray($('input[name="regioni_gestite_ag[]"]:checkbox:checked')
                          .map(function() { return $(this).val() }));
```

Comment: ah right, forgot about that, we should use `.each` + `$(this).val()`, right?

Comment: @Kledi: The selector [works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/q67Me/). If you still have trouble after reading the answer please be more specific.

Comment: @StockOverflaw: Yes, if you want to get all the values that's one way to go (`.map()` is another).

Comment: Hey, could you please update the answer with that, .each + $(this.... 
i have no idea where to put this in javascript.. i'll try it then maybe thee's something else wrong..

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work.. now lease let me show you how i print the values which tell me undefined:

$postRegioni_gestite_ag = $_POST["postRegioni_gestite_ag"];

Comment: And this is the js part:
'&postRegioni_gestite_ag=' + js_regioni_gestite_ag

Comment: @Kledi: You are doing the JS part completely wrong. jQuery has `.serialize()`, use it.

Comment: last question plese, where in the above writings should i write .serialize()>

Comment: @Kledi: Sorry, but it's not possible to write code like this. You will have to go and read some examples from the manual.

Comment: One question please, is there something wrong with my form in html maybe? i guess, i should put id[] or something? since the form as it seems takes the id part, not name

Answer (score 0):

Try with [starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector (`^=`) , like so:

```
var js_regioni_gestite_ag = $('input:checkbox[name^=regioni_gestite_ag]:checked').val();
```